# bringSubviewToFront moves UIView back to original location

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a view with drag and drop gestures.  If a user drags and drops a view over another view, it will switch places with that view.  During the drag `UIPanGestureRecognizer` method, I use `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)` to bring the dragged view on top of the other views.

But when I call `bringSubviewToFront` on a recently dropped view, that view will immediately move back to its original position. If you turn off AutoLayout, it works fine.

```
    func draggedViewHandler(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if(sender.state == .Began)
        {
            // If you drag the recently dropped view, this line will cause the view to jump back
            // to its original position that was layout in Autolayout.  If you turn off Autoview, it works fine.
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
        }

        [additional code...]
    }
```

Here is a full working copy of the project in Swift.

https://github.com/duyn9uyen/SwiftDragAndDropAutoLayoutBug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put your finger on the matter. Think of it this way:

- Auto Layout positions views.
- You are positioning a view (in code).

Well, those two things are in conflict. You must not do what you are doing.

If you want to move a view in code, when that view is also under the influence of Auto Layout, you must *change the constraints* that position it, so that Auto Layout positions it where you want it. If you are going to use Auto Layout on a view, then in repositioning it, you must work *with* Auto Layout, not against it.